# Got stuck in Emergency mode with ACPI Error

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, root-filesystem, system-recovery

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I probably have done sth which damaged the system file. After reboot, I am stucked in emergency mode. The error is about ACPI like below. I am not sure what is wrong here. Could anyone offer me some suggestion? I really need some help.
[image]

Comment: did you do what the message tells you to do?

Comment: @jsotola And what exactly would the error message tell him to do?  Let's try to be a little more constructive with our comments (this isn't reddit).  -OP, can you give us a little more information on your system setup and bios configuration?

Comment: @bgregs, it instructs the OP to use the `journalctl -xb` command to view the system logs